# Two sided Rayleigh Ritz

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix.
Then from Rayleigh Ritz,
$\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}=\lambda_\max$.
My question is, for a symmetric and positive semi definite matrix, is the following true? 
$$\sup_{x,y\neq 0} \frac{y^TAx}{\sqrt{y^Ty\cdot x^Tx}}=\lambda_\max$$
I'm seeking a reference or a counterexample, or related theorems.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\lambda_k,v_k)$ denote the eigenpairs with $\lambda_1\ge ...\lambda_n\ge0$ and $v_i^T v_j =\delta_{ij}$. Write $x =\sum_i c_i v_i$ and $y=\sum_j d_jv_j$. Thus 
$$ \sup_{x,y\neq0} y^TAx/(||x||\cdot||y||) = \sup_{||x||=||y||=1}  y^TAx = \sup_{...} \sum_{i,j} c_j d_i \lambda_j v_j^Tv_i= \sup_{...} \sum_j c_jd_j \lambda_j $$ 
Now it is clear that $x,y$ cannot be such that $x^Ty<0$ for the supremum. So 
$$ \sum_i \lambda_i c_id_i\le \lambda_1\sum_i c_i d_i \le \lambda_1$$ 
where the last inequality is due to Cauchy-Schwarz. By choosing $x=y=v_1$ we have the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer!